# URL Mod-Rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

I currently have a working URL:

> http://example.com/security-services.php?service=fixed-camera-surveillance

and then I have PHP say, `$_REQUEST['service']` to do some stuff...

But I'd like to achieve the same function if the URL looked like this:

> http://example.com/security-services/fixed-camera-surveillance

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

An `.htaccess` file with something like this should do it.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule security-services/(.*)/? security-services.php?service=$1 [L]
```

The part that says `security-services/(.*)/?` matches the URL in the browser and rewrites it to `security-services.php`.

The key part is the `(.*)` which captures that portion of the URL and passes it to the PHP script as a GET value.

Comment: Thanks for replying!

I've done what you've suggested and the page loads fine.  The only problem I'm facing is capturing the 'service' variable.

Let's say I want to test it, on the original example I'd have:
http://example.com/security-services.php?service=fixed-camera-surveillance
and could test with "echo $_REQUEST['service']"

New example,
http://example.com/security-services/fixed-camera-surveillance
I want "fixed-camera-surveillance' to be echo'd.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried it? the code above does it, it takes anything it finds with the `(.*)` regex and dumps it where you see the `$1`, so your script at the `security-services.php` file.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it.  I want to capture 'fixed-camera-surveillance' from the URL '.../security-services/fixed-camera-surveillance'.  Would I be asking for ['service'] as before, or is it just stored in $1?

Comment: The first group of () is $1, the second $2, and so on.  So you can capture multiple things and then use them in the rewrite part of the rule.

Comment: Thanks Mark for getting back to me.  I'm sorry; either I'm misunderstanding you, or you to me (probably to former).  I've implemented your solution, as is.  Could you *literally* write a PHP command to get the contents of /.../ (or $1 as you've described).  <? echo $_REQUEST['services']; ?> is not doing the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: **Edit to last sentence in last comment » <? echo $_REQUEST['service']; ?>

Comment: it should, although I prefer <?php echo $_GET['service']; ?> just to check all the boxes, your file is called `.htaccess` and it is uploaded into either the folder you're working in or the root folder. Also, can you confirm that the `security-services.php` file is actually being run, it's just not receiving the value? or  is nothing happening?

Comment: Like MalphasWats says, $_GET['service'] should do the trick.  You might add a print_r($_GET); just to see what the contents of $_GET actually are.

Comment: It was $_GET all along!  Rookie mistake.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Stack_Overflow, reviewing comments to an answer is very cumbersome.  If there are 6+ comments to a particular answer (or as I call it, a discussion) the most recent comments are hidden until someone clicks "add/show X more comments."  Just wanted to share some usability feedback.

Comment: Alright, I goofed up when I said $_GET got it to work.  It's not.  To illustrate, I'm set up a print_r($_GET) and storing that output in <meta name="stackoverflowOutput"> at the bottom of the <head>, so you all can see.  Here is the working example » http://tr.im/msex1, here is the desired, non-working example » http://tr.im/msex2

Comment: My working, .htaccess is located in the site root (/) and looks like this,

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^security-services/(.*) /security-services.php?service=$1 [L]

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^security-services/([^/]+)$ security-services.php?service=$1 [L]
```

The `[^/]+` describes the next path segment after `/security-services`, `(…)` forms a group that’s match then can referenced to with `$1` in the substitution.

And if you want a more general for any kind of `…-service.php` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/-]+)-services/([^/]+)$ $1-services.php?service=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying!

I've done what you've suggested and the page loads fine.  The only problem I'm facing is capturing the 'service' variable.

Let's say I want to test it, on the original example I'd have:
http://example.com/security-services.php?service=fixed-camera-surveillance
and could test with "echo $_REQUEST['service']"

New example,
http://example.com/security-services/fixed-camera-surveillance
I want "fixed-camera-surveillance' to be echo'd.

Suggestions?

Comment: @Mike B.: That should work the same way. You shouldn’t notice any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^security-services/(.*)/? /security-services.php?service=$1
```

If you're using a .conf file, change `^` to `^/`